# Maintenance plan for SQL Server Database Mirroring

Tags: sql-server, cluster, mirror

We're using SQL Server database mirroring and we're trying to create a db maintenance plan to backup the database. The problem is that when the server is not the primary database the plan fails. I was wondering what the best-practice is in this situation and is there a way to have the maintenance plan backup up only the primary database?

Comment: +1, because you just parroted *my* question while I was stuck at site  ;)

Comment: yes, yes I did ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard and fast recommendation that i have found - 
One option
Recreate the jobs and dependencies on the mirror server with the jobs disabled

Then use a WMI alert on the  DATABASE_MIRRORING_STATE_CHANGE to enable / disable the job
This job would also run on the primary and disable the job on failover - see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabasemirroring/thread/ba56240d-7182-4c92-b387-ff2068082e10/) link for another variation

You could create a backup stored procedure with logic to only backup a database that is not in a restoring state like [this](http://blog.ola.hallengren.com/_attachments/3440068/DatabaseBackup.sql)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SQL 2008 the Backup Task has a lovely "Ignore Databases when the State is not online" option.  This bypasses databases in a Restoring/Mirroring state for you.

For a SQL 2000 Box you can check the following property on each database

```
SELECT NAME FROM sysdatabases WHERE databasepropertyex(sysdatabases .Name, 'Status') = 'ONLINE'
```

For a SQL 2005 + Box you can use this

```
SELECT NAME FROM sys.databases systemdatabases  WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'
```

Then only backup databases that meet that criteria.

Comment: yep, i use this too.. create the job on both principle & mirror & you're done

Answer (score 1):

There should be a way, having a T-SQL Statement Task in the Maintenance Plan performing:

```
declare @primary bit = 0
select @primary=1
from sys.database_mirroring
where mirroring_role = 1
```

and using @primary as a condition to start the backup sequence.
Please, let me know if it helped.
Cheers

Comment: Won't work.  Maintenance plans don't have access to those variables.  See this: http://serverfault.com/questions/47117/add-conditions-to-maintenance-plan-sequence-on-sql-server