# DPM server and mirrored SQL-server cluster

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2005, mirror, scdpm

I want to use Data Protection Manager 2007 to backup two servers with SQL-server that have several mirrored databases.

On
[Maintenance plan for SQL Server Database Mirroring](https://serverfault.com/questions/3756/maintenance-plan-for-sql-server-database-mirroring)
someone helpfully describes that for e.g. a maintenance plan one has to roll custom scripts to enable or disable these plans.

Now if I use the DPM 2007 GUI to select what to protect I won't see the databases on the second server that are in recovering state.

What should I do?

Can I somehow make SQL server (2005) to prefer one instance over the other so that the mirrored database always switches back to the main node after e.g. automatic windows updates?

Or should I "trick" DPM by first planning a backup of all database on the first node, then do manual failover and then reselect them?

I have not tried it, will it tolerate the failures? Or stop working? In any case I think it will nag regularly.

Anyway, have the data backuped twice is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Can I somehow make SQL server (2005) to prefer one instance over the other so that the mirrored database always switches back to the main node after e.g. automatic windows updates?**

No.  Database mirroring will never automatically fail back over if it's currently running on a server that isn't broken.

**2. Or should I "trick" DPM by first planning a backup of all database on the first node, then do manual failover and then reselect them?**

Set up DPM on both servers.  It'll back up the databases that are online on this server.  You should do this anyway just because if the primary server dies, you still need to do backups on the secondary server until the primary one comes back up.